# ASP.NET MVC - Automatic notifications when a record is modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have just used the NotifyIcon class in a windows application and I think it is really handy. I'm predominantly a web developer so I just wanted to find out if there is anything similar to this for a website.

The website I want to incorporate this into has a Ticket Management module where users can capture tickets/problems and then get responses to these tickets from my client's employees who handle the ticket.

Obviously I realize that the notification or pop up will need to be shown in the page, but is there a way to put a timer on the specific page, or even the Master page (maybe javascript or JQuery), to poll the database every few minutes and check for recently modified tickets and let the logged in user know that a ticket has been updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site does exactly what you're saying :)

Comment: Actually, yes it does. But do you know how? Does it use SignalR like Judo suggested?

Comment: I don't know about this site, but there's a great presentation from Scott Hanselman about SignalIR and ASP.NET MVC  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETForMobileOneASPNETAndRealtimeASPNETWithSignalrVideoOfScottHanselmansTalksInRussia.aspx

Comment: @kubal5003 SignalR won't work for me. My company is still utilizing MVC 1 in .NET Framework 3.5. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the client to keep an open connection  to the server and poll it, I think Signal R will be your best bet for integrating into an .NET project. It is on Nuget but source is at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR.

Comment: For the sake of pedanticism: this wouldn't be polling. AFAIK SignalR implements a publish/subscribe model.

Comment: The connection doesn't have to be kept open. That's why a timer would be useful. Once the the condition is met, it opens the connection, polls the required table and then closes the connection and if any tickets are modified, it notifies the user with a pop up.

Comment: @millimoose I only used it on one project but it I didn't see a publish/subscribe model at all. The default for SignalR is long polling but it will also work with WebSockets when available.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but SignalR only works with VS2010 i.e. MVC 3 or higher?

Comment: It requires .NET 4.0 or higher

Comment: @Judo I thought so. Unfortunately, the company I work for is still using MVC 1 .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: @Judo No idea what technique they're implemented with, but [`Hub`s](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) certainly seem to expose a PubSub-ish abstraction. `PersistentConnection`s are also capable of broadcasting to all connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend familiarizing yourself with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org).

Node.js is a strong tool that aids in leveraging javascript as a real-time server management tool.

After you've gotten yourself familiarized with the Node.js setup, you'll want to grab [Socket.io](http://socket.io). Socket.io provides suppport for the long-polling technique by leveraging against your websocket created by Node.js. Here, we can manage the conditions at which we serve data. This is a huge tool on the developers side in battling against `2 HTTPD ports`.